# design of one row in android listview

Tags: android, listview, fragment

I need help with my android app. I need customize items in listview. My app works with fragments. I don’t know how to implement list_item.xml to my code.

KartyListFragment.java

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.karty_list, container, false);
    return view;
}
```

karty_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/prazdna_db"
    android:textColor="#f00"
    android:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to designed one row in list_item.xml but i don´t know how to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[here](http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.ro/2012/07/android-listview-tutorial.html) you can find a good tutorial to build your list view.. I think it will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Jus create the layout you want and pass it along to the list adapter as the view to be inflated. For example, using a `SimpleAdapter`:

```
mAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, list, R.layout.my_custom_list_item, from, to);
mListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```